# Explanation of Github fork and how they store files

Tags: git, version-control, github, git-svn

I am just wondering what happens when a fork is done on github.

For example, when I fork a project does it make a copy on github server of all of that code, or just create a link to it?

So another question:
In git since it hashes all the files if you add the same file to it it does not need to store the file contents again because the hash will be already in the system, correct?

Is github like this? So if I happen to upload the exact same piece of code as another user, when github gits it does it essentially just create a link to that file since it would have the same hash, or does it save all of its contents again separately?

Any enlightenment would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[github.com](http://github.com) is exactly the same semantics as git, but with a web-based GUI interface wrapped around it.

[Storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29#Data): "Git stores each revision of a file as a unique blob object"
So each file is stored uniquely, but it uses a SHA-1 hash to determine changes from file to file.

As for github, a fork is essentially a clone. This means that a new fork is a new area of storage on their servers, with a reference to its ORIGIN. It in no way would set up links between the two, because git by nature can track remotes. Each fork knows the upstream.

When you say "if I happen to upload the exact same piece of code as another user", the term "upload" is a bit vague in the "git" sense. If you are working on the same repository and git even allows you to commit the same file, that means it was different and it checked in that revision.  But if you mean working on a clone/fork of another repo, it would be the same situation, but also there would be no links made on the filesystem to the other repo.

I can't claim to have any intimate knowledge of what optimizations github might be making under the hood, on their internal system. They could possibly be doing intermediate custom operations to save on disk space. But anything they would be doing would be transparent to you and would not matter much, since effectively it should always operate under expected git semantics.

A developer at github [wrote a blog post](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html) about how they internally do their own git workflow. While it doesn't relate to your question about how they manage the actual workflow of the service, I think this quote from the conclusion is pretty informative:

> Git itself is fairly complex to understand, making the workflow that
>   you use with it more complex than necessary is simply adding more
>   mental overhead to everybody’s day. I would always advocate using the
>   simplest possible system that will work for your team and doing so
>   until it doesn’t work anymore and then adding complexity only as
>   absolutely needed.

What I take away from that, is they acknowledge how complex git is by itself, so most likely they take the lightest touch possible to wrap around it to provide the service, and let git do what it does best natively.

Comment: It's possible that github uses some kind of optimisation like hardlinks while creating the fork but for all practical purposes, it's just a clone on the github server itself.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: Sure. It is definitely possible that they strive to make internal optimization to save on disk space until a fork actually commits a revision to the file. But that would be transparent to the users really. Good point though.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: Though as a I think about it more, that might be a complicated situation, because as we know, when the upstream repo receives new commits, it has no effect on the forks. They are responsible for fetching downstream individually.

Comment: @jdi So if you have a large enough repository (say 100 megs) and enough people fork it, you'll start to look at respectable amounts of storage?

Comment: @R0MANARMY: On github? They don't have storage limits. And even if they did, someone forking your repo would count against them and not you. But yes it would duplicate data. github does have "soft" storage limits in that they want to prevent blatant abuse (like committing huge files), but again someone else forking it is on them.

Comment: I know they don't limit you, but they still have hard drives in their servers, and those are large but not infinite.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: yes. And what is your point? What I said in my answer is i dont presume to know the custom hooks and layers they add to optimize storage. Only that git is git whether it is via github or any other provider. Anything else doesnt matter to the end user. If they imposed a hard storage limit on you then you would have to consider that amongst your projects. But forked projects irrelevant to that concept since it would be a per user quota

Comment: @jdi: Yes but once a blob is written it doesn't change. That's how git is organised. The entire repository will not be linked but the individual blobs can be. I don't know how `filter-branch` might affect it though. Look through the manual page of `git-clone` for `hardlinks`.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: I suppose the only way to know the github pipeline for sure would be to get the low-down from a github employee :-)

Comment: Yup but it's fun to speculate.

Comment: So basically from what you say, if someone had a repository that has 10gb and 100 people forked it, just to push a patch that has few kb, github would need to allocate almost 1tb of space? that sounds pretty ineffective

Comment: @Petr : no that isn't what I was saying. I described github as being a layer over git semantics, but also stated that I have no knowledge of what optimizations they are doing under the hood. I was also using their own quotes and references. For all I know they may use a copy-on-write style where a fork uses symlinks until discreet blobs are required for revisions. My answer described git in general and provided what public info was available about githubs implementation.

Comment: I think that a fork will create just a branch named `user/branch` because if you fork a project and commit something there, your hash will be visible in the original repo too

Answer (score 10):

According to https://enterprise.github.com/releases/2.2.0/notes GitHub Enterprise (and I assume GitHub) somehow shares objects between forks to reduce disk space usage:

> This release changes the way GitHub Enterprise stores repositories,
>   which reduces disk usage by sharing Git objects between forks and
>   improves caching performance when reading repository data.

There's also more details about how they do it at https://githubengineering.com/counting-objects.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how exactly GitHub do it, but here is a possible way. It requires some knowledge of the way git stores its data.

The short answer is that the repos can *share* the `objects` database but each have their own references.
We can even simulate it locally for a proof-of-concept.

In the directory of a bare repo (or in the `.git/` subdir if it is not bare) there are three things that are the minimum for a repo to work:

- the `objects/` subdirectory, which stores all the objects (commits, trees, blobs ...). They are stored either individually as files with names equal to the hash of the object or in `.pack` files.
- the `refs/` subdirectory, which stores simple files like `refs/heads/master` whose contents is the hash of the object it references.
- the `HEAD` file, which says what is the current commit. Its value is either a raw hash (which corresponds to a *detached head* i.e we are not on any named branch) or a textual link to a ref where the actual hash can be found (for example `ref: refs/heads/master` - that would mean we are on branch `master`)

Let's suppose someone creates his original (not forking) repo `orig` at Github.
To simulate, locally we do

```
$ git init --bare github_orig
```

We imagine that the above happens at the Github servers. Now there is an empty github rpository. Then we imagine that from our own PC we clone the github repo:

```
$ git clone github_orig local_orig
```

Of course in real life instead of `github_orig` we will use `https://github...`. Now we have cloned the github repo in `local_orig`.

```
$ cd local_orig/
$ echo zzz > file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m initial
$ git push
$ cd ..
```

After this `github_orig`'s `object` dir will contain our pushed commit object, one blob object for `file` and one tree object. The `refs/heads/master` file will contain the commit hash.

Now let's image what could be happening when someone hits the `Fork` button.
We will create a git repo but *by hand*:

```
$ mkdir github_fork
$ cd github_fork/
$ cp ../github_orig/HEAD .
$ cp -r ../github_orig/refs .
$ ln -s ../github_orig/objects
$ cd ..
```

Notice that we *copy* `HEAD` and `refs` but we make a *symbolic link* for `objects`. As we can see making a *fork* is very cheap. Even if we have tens of branches each of them is simply a file in the `refs/heads` directory which contains a simple hexadecimal hash (40 bytes). For `objects` we only link to the original objects directory - we do not copy anything!

Now we simulate that the user making the fork, clones the forked repo locally:

```
$ git clone github_fork local_fork
$ cd local_fork
$ # ls
.git/  file
```

We can see that we have successfully cloned although the repo that we clone from does not have its own `objects` but links to that of the original repo.
Now the forking user may make branches, commits and then push them to `github_fork`. Objects will be pushed in the `objects` directory which is the same for `github_orig`! But `refs` and `HEAD` will be modified and will no longer match the ones at the `github_orig`.

So the bottom line is that all repos that belong to the same forking tree share a *common objects pool* while each repo contains its own references. Anyone who pushes commits to his own forked repo modifies his own references but puts the objects in a shared pool.

Of course to be really usable some more things must be taken care of - most importantly the git garbage collector must *not* be invoked unless the repo where it is invoked in has the knowledge of *all* references - not just it's own. Otherwise it could discard objects in the shared pool which are not reachable from its references but could be reachable from other repos' refs.

Comment: If I read correctly, this is *the correct answer.*