# How does GitHub reduce storage waste?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have read multiple times that GitHub reduces waste by NOT storing EVERY file in clones, but only the files that change. [Source](http://www.nextplatform.com/2015/09/24/inside-the-github-systems-where-open-source-lives/)

How does it do this or how can I replicate this type of feature, as I was not able to find this feature in Git?

Note that I don't mind using other VCS that has this functionality.

Comment: They are co-hosting forks on the same machine and use a shared repository storage backend.

Comment: Related (but there was better discussion about it here, too, cannot find it right now): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974686/explanation-of-github-fork-and-how-they-store-files

Comment: Blog from GitHub team about their storage backend (which is just Git basically): http://githubengineering.com/introducing-dgit/

Comment: @Thilo this is interesting but I don't understand how this explains how GitHub avoids storage wastage by storing only the files that changes in forks

Comment: Git already does that. In a branch, only changed files ("objects") need to be stored. A fork can be just a clone on the same server, with the same object repository attached. That way, a fork is essentially the same as a branch (as far as storage is concerned).

Comment: @Thilo So your saying that clones should be stored on the server internally on the server as a branch?

Comment: Not as a branch. But you can register a common object storage for all your git repositories on the same server. My understanding is that this is what Github does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304374/what-are-the-differences-between-git-clone-shared-and-reference

Comment: @Thilo What do you mean by common object storage? Do you mean use `git clone --shared`?

Comment: All I am saying is that you can have more than one repository share the same disk space for their objects. This functionality is already provided by git core.

Comment: @Thilo Thanks. Please summarise your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The Github team has put up [a fairly detailed article about their storage layer](http://githubengineering.com/introducing-dgit/).

An interesting aspect is that they do not suffer from NIH-syndrome, but based all their work on top of existing functionality in the core git system.

> Perhaps it’s surprising that GitHub’s repository-storage tier, DGit, is built using the same technologies. Why not a SAN? A distributed file system? Some other magical cloud technology that abstracts away the problem of storing bits durably?
>
> The answer is simple: it’s fast and it’s robust.

So, to come back to your question:

You can (in core git) [configure a shared object storage location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23304374/what-are-the-differences-between-git-clone-shared-and-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1) to be used together by more than one repository.

Github makes use of this by co-locating forks of repositories on the same server (or set of servers, for redundancy and availability). As a result, any duplicate objects (and there will be many in a fork) will need to be stored just once.